# Starting gnome-terminal and automatically run specific process (roscore)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, tmux

I'm typing

```
$ roscore
```

and It starts succesfuly.

`$ run_roscore.sh` is succesfully too.
run_roscore.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roscore

exec $SHELL
```

But I've adding shortcut to cairo-dock(or menu via alacarte), when I clicked, terminal screen was **appears and exits**. And there is no running `roscore` process in system.

Cairo-Dock's shortcut's command box;

```
gnome-terminal -e run_roscore.sh
```

I've tried them before:

```
run_roscore.sh
bash -c "/usr/bin/run_roscore.sh"
gnome-terminal -x roscore
gnome-terminal -e /usr/bin/run_roscore.sh
```

**But always terminal appears and exits.**  I've just disabled auto exiting, Now, I wrote this `gnome-terminal -x roscore` to command box(on cairo-dock or menu item or Alt + F2 box). It says:
`Failed to execute child process "roscore" (No such file or directory)`

***Edit:*** User luator suggested `tmux`. But it doesn't works with tmux too.

With a `gnome-terminal -e tmux` command, terminal screen opens and it runs tmux succesfully. And I typed roscore in tmux, It works. I typed `tmux -c ls` or `tmux -c roscore` in opened gnome-terminal, It works. But in shortcut(or Alt + F2 to run command), `gnome-terminal -e 'tmux -c roscore'` doesn't works.

I want to `roscore` process in background, or if it isn't possible without terminal screen, I want to start terminal and automatically call `roscore` when i clicked to shortcut (menu shortcut or cairo-dock shortcut).
So what is the solution for creating shortcut?

Comment: **I've just disabled** "exiting terminal" **option. And It says;**
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
    `File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roscore", line 62, in <module>`
        `import roslaunch`
`ImportError: No module named roslaunch`

Comment: Do you source the `setup.bash` of your workspace in your `.bashrc`? This is necessary for the ROS stuff to be found.

Comment: Yes, last lines in .bashrc :
`...`
`#source /opt/tinyos-2.1.1/tinyos.sh`

`source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok I found solution** when I was trying `roscd`. I typed;

`$roscd beginner_tutorials`

and It said:

```
roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'
```

Then I typed;

```
$source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

And `roscd` worked.

This command is already in my .bashrc file. I added to my script's top too:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
bash -c "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roscore"

exec $SHELL
```

In cairo-dock's command box, just:

```
run_roscore.sh
```

And shortcut's "*Run in a terminal*" option is checked. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a terminal multiplexer like [screen](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) to run `roscore` in the background (start screen or tmux in a terminal, run roscore, detach).

To get a clickable shortcut that does this for you, you can create a launcher using the following command:

```
tmux new -ds ros roscore
```

This starts a new tmux session with the name *ros* (name specified by `-s`), runs the command `roscore` in this session and detaches from it automatically (`-d`).

To reattach to the tmux session (e.g. to kill the roscore) use the following command in a terminal:

```
tmux attach -t ros
```

(The same should be possible with `screen` if you prefer it over `tmux`, just dig a bit in the manual)

Comment: with `gnome-terminal -e tmux` command, terminal screen opens and runs tmux succesfully. and I typed roscore, it works. I typed `tmux -c ls` or `tmux -c roscore` in opened gnome-terminal, it worked. But in shortcut, `gnome-terminal - e 'tmux -c roscore'` doesn't works. There is only blank terminal with shell.

Comment: @OrhanGaziHafif Sorry, but I have to admit that I don't have an idea what could be the problem :(. For me (using Xfce as desktop environment) it works with a launcher that contains just the command from my answer. I suggest you edit your question and add what you wrote in your comment (this way it is more likely to be seen by others). In this case also consider to add the [tag:tmux] tag to the question so people with more experience in tmux will see it.

Comment: I can't edit comment. I wrote it wrong. I will edit question. Thank you for help. I can't vote useful because of my reputation.